# Nodejs app structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

I'm wondering if I'm structuring my nodejs app accordingly to account for best performance. My major concern is in regards to how I'm passing in moving my app reference around modules.

Basically in my app.js file I'm declaring all of my requires, libraries etc:

```
var app = {
    config     : require('../../config.json'),
    restify    : require('restify'),
    path       : require('path'),
    mongo      : require('mongodb'),
    model      : require('./models.js'),
    step       : require('step'),
    q          : require('q'),
    api        : require('./api_util.js'),
    underscore : require('underscore')
};
```

In my exports I'm passing in the entire app object. Now given my knowledge of JavaScript (you can correct me if I'm wrong), this will not create new instances of the object, it will simply pass in the object as a pointer and reference the same object in memory.

Now what I find myself doing aside from that (for ease) is in my restify library (the same can be done with Express), I'm appending the app value to the server request object like so:

```
app.server.pre(function (request, response, next) {
    request.app = app;
    return next();
});
```

Hence on every single request if I need quick access to any of my library declarations, config etc. I can easily access request.app. I don't see this being an issue either, same logic the object acts a pointer back to the same memory space, so I'm not doubling memory usage or anything.

Is there a better/easier way of structuring this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct about references being passed instead of objects being duplicated. From that point of view, you are not wasting extra space when passing references to your `app`.

However, I would advise you against doing this: if you pass a reference to `app` around everywhere, what it tells me is that you don't really know what you will need in this or that module.

You should carefully plan your dependencies and know what each module will need so that you can pass the right dependencies for each module in your app.

Regarding things like `underscore` or `mongodb`, you should not be doing what you are doing. You should only pass around modules that need initialization. For things like `underscore` or `mongodb`, node.js caches the definition the first time you `require()` it, so you can really call `require` at the top of every module that needs it.

This will not incur any performance loss, and it will make it clearer what library each module requires.

Comment: Hmmmm, it will also help dry up my case and make maintenance a lot easier. Ok I see what you mean. That being side, if I *do* strip my libraries from app do you think I should still use things like server.pre() to pass my app around or again depend on the require method?

Comment: I think you should use `require` wherever possible. Not only will this make it clear what you need for each module, but it will decouple your modules and facilitate their usage in other places in the future.

When too much stuff depends on each other, it's not only hard to debug but also hard to reuse code.

Comment: Also, remember that `require()` caches loaded modules, and will reuse the same `underscore` if you require it in different files. So its safe to use as often as you need.